# sql if exists then do some calculations

Tags: sql

I have a table `Tb1` containing  some columns such as: `OTI` and `SumOfTb`.

There is another `Tb2` containing cols: `Id` and `Date`.

The link between the above tables is `Tb1.OTI = Tb2.Id`

What I want to achieve:

if `Date` ( from Tb2 ) exists => `myResult = SumOfTb`

if `Date` ( from Tb2 ) not exist => `myResult = 0`

Obviously, not all entries from `Tb1` have a correspondence in `Tb2`

How can I achieve this?

Comment: which dbms are you using and can you please provide some data and the result you are expecting

Comment: `Date` is a parameter?

Comment: @deterministicFail: RDBMS, I gave a quick name example for a column, so I gave "Date", I do know it is a reserved word

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT T1.OTI
,ISNULL(SUMOFTB,0) AS MyResult --Or equivalent function in your DBMS
FROM TB1 T1
      LEFT JOIN TB2 T2 ON T1.OTI = T2.ID
```

Comment: ISNULL is product specific, which dbms? (No dbms specified in question...)

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT IF(Tb1.SumOfIb IS NULL, 0, Tb1.SumOfTb) as myResult
FROM Tb2 INNER JOIN Tb1 ON (TB1.OTI = Tb2.Id)
WHERE Tb2.Date = 'your_date'
```

Comment: Product specific SQL here, for which dbms? (No dbms specified in question...)

Answer (score 0):

If a t2 date exists, then t2.date is NOT NULL and SumOfTb is returned. Else 0 is returned.

```
select case when t2."date" is NOT NULL then t1.SumOfTb
            else  0
       end AS MyResult
from t1
  left join t2 on Tb1.OTI = Tb2.Id
```

The double quotes for `"date"` are there because date is a reserved word in ANSI SQL, so that column name has to be delimited.